# How to download the form field as PDF using JS or PHP or Anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I am using this code for upload a `CSV` file to `html` table.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Darious/z8vcqeup/)

Now, I have to download the table as `PDF` format, when the button click.

How can I do this using `JS` or PHP or Any?, But how to define the php file in html?

Someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This won't be easy because this is not the thing what JS is used to do... Still you can try the following:

1. Try [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to generate the PDF file
2. Show save dialog, there are many solutions for that, e.g. try this one [Javascript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13405129/1990451)